# How to show "apply discount" option on checkout magento 2

Tags: checkout, discount, magento-2.1.8

I want to use apply discount option on the checkout page. How can I show this?

Comment: you mean discount coupon code which is apply  in cart page?

Comment: Coupon code form on checkout page.

Comment: I think Magento 2 by default provides coupon code option in checkout page.

Answer (score 2):

In your custom theme folder you can add block by override checkout_index_index.xml.

**Go to**

> /vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

**Paste it to**

> /app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Theme]/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

**Paste below code in body tag**

```
<referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Coupon" name="checkout.cart.coupon" as="coupon" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/coupon.phtml" after="-"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

call block in checkout_index_index.xml

```
<block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Coupon" name="checkout.cart.coupon" as="coupon" template="cart/coupon.phtml"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an advanced function My Suggestion:

https://github.com/hodongnhut/magento2-payment-discount

[image]